Lambda function not able to import custom module defined in lambda layer NodeJS v20
I am trying to create a NodeJS lambda layer to contain some reusable code. The layer structure looks like this:

The index.mjs file contains my custom module. When creating the layer, I have defined the runtime to be nodejs 20.x.
Now, when I am trying to import my custom module inside my lambda function, I am getting below error:
Response
{
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module '/opt/nodejs/node/node_modules/index.mjs' imported from /var/task/index.mjs",
  "trace": [
    "Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/opt/nodejs/node/node_modules/index.mjs' imported from /var/task/index.mjs",
    "    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:269:11)",
    "    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:937:10)",
    "    at moduleResolveWithNodePath (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1161:14)",
    "    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1204:79)",
    "    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:383:12)",
    "    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:352:25)",
    "    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:227:38)",
    "    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:87:39)",
    "    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:86:36)"
  ]
}

Function Logs
2024-06-18T06:30:26.475Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"Cannot find module '/opt/nodejs/node/node_modules/index.mjs' imported from /var/task/index.mjs","code":"ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND","url":"file:///opt/nodejs/node/node_modules/index.mjs","stack":["Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/opt/nodejs/node/node_modules/index.mjs' imported from /var/task/index.mjs","    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:269:11)","    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:937:10)","    at moduleResolveWithNodePath (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1161:14)","    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1204:79)","    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:383:12)","    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:352:25)","    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:227:38)","    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:87:39)","    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:86:36)"]}
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 149.01 ms    Phase: init Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.Unknown
2024-06-18T06:30:26.744Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"Cannot find module '/opt/nodejs/node/node_modules/index.mjs' imported from /var/task/index.mjs","code":"ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND","url":"file:///opt/nodejs/node/node_modules/index.mjs","stack":["Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/opt/nodejs/node/node_modules/index.mjs' imported from /var/task/index.mjs","    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:269:11)","    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:937:10)","    at moduleResolveWithNodePath (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1161:14)","    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1204:79)","    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:383:12)","    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:352:25)","    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:227:38)","    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:87:39)","    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:86:36)"]}
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 311.12 ms    Phase: invoke   Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.Unknown
START RequestId: fee4b93a-3ef2-45d3-bdf0-ad84045b3205 Version: $LATEST
Unknown application error occurred
Runtime.Unknown
END RequestId: fee4b93a-3ef2-45d3-bdf0-ad84045b3205
REPORT RequestId: fee4b93a-3ef2-45d3-bdf0-ad84045b3205  Duration: 312.04 ms Billed Duration: 313 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 12 MB

Request ID
fee4b93a-3ef2-45d3-bdf0-ad84045b3205

My lambda function looks like this:
// import * as JwyVerifier from "/opt/nodejs/node20/node_modules/jwt-verify.service";
// import * as JwyVerifier from "/opt/nodejs/node20/node_modules/jwt-verify.service";
// import * as JwtVerifier from "/opt/nodejs/node_modules/jwt-verify.service.mjs";
// import * as JwtVerifier from "/opt/nodejs/node_modules/index.mjs";
// import * as JwtVerifier from "/opt/nodejs/node20/node_modules/index.mjs";

export const handler = async (event) => {
  // TODO implement
  console.log(process.env.NODE_PATH)
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify('Hello from LAMBDA!'),
  };
  return response;
};

The output of the process.env.NODE_PATH is this:
/opt/nodejs/node20/node_modules:/opt/nodejs/node_modules:/var/runtime/node_modules:/var/runtime:/var/task

I have tried putting in the runtime in the path as well as creating folder as suggested here and here but none worked. Please advice.
PS: I am using NodeJS v20.x for my lambda function and my lambda layer.

I was able to solve it. I had to write a function using NodeJS readdir function to check where the layer code is actually getting stored. Once I found out that location, I was able to import my required items. I wrote a detailed post https://vanu-verma.medium.com/creating-and-using-a-lambda-layer-inside-lambda-function-in-nodejs-v20-part-1-40bb306a8c66 in case anyone is interested to check my solution.
